# Problem when converting Numbers to Letters in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a problem converting numbers to letters, the problem is when I enter the number 101 it only says "satu"

I want the number 10 to define the word "Seratus". I have changed the Length but when I enter 101 it says "sepuluh satu" which I want it says "seratus satu" instead of "Sepuluh Satu"

How to define the number 10 (sepuluh) to be 10 (seratus)

Here is the code that I used

```
    Public Function konversi(ByVal angka As Integer) As String
    Select Case angka
        Case 0 : konversi = ""
        Case 1 : konversi = " Satu"
        Case 2 : konversi = " Dua"
        Case 3 : konversi = " Tiga"
        Case 4 : konversi = " Empat"
        Case 5 : konversi = " Lima"
        Case 6 : konversi = " Enam"
        Case 7 : konversi = " Tujuh"
        Case 8 : konversi = " Delapan"
        Case 9 : konversi = " Sembilan"
        Case 10 : konversi = "Sepuluh"
        Case 11 : konversi = "Sebelas"
        Case 12 : konversi = "Dua belas"
        Case 13 : konversi = "Tiga belas"
        Case 14 : konversi = "Empat belas"
        Case 15 : konversi = "Lima belas"
        Case 16 : konversi = "Enam belas"
        Case 17 : konversi = "Tujuh belas"
        Case 18 : konversi = "Delapan belas"
        Case 19 : konversi = "Sembilan belas"
        Case 100 : konversi = "Seratus"

    End Select
End Function

Public Function terbilang(ByVal bil As Integer) As String
    Dim cbil, bil1, bil2 As Integer
    cbil = Trim(Str(bil))
    If Len(cbil) = 1 Then
        terbilang = konversi(bil)
    Else
        If Strings.Left(cbil, 1) = "1" Then
            terbilang = konversi(bil)
        Else
            bil1 = Val(Strings.Left(cbil, 1))
            bil2 = Val(Strings.Right(cbil, 1))
            terbilang = konversi(bil1) + " Puluh" + konversi(bil2)
        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Sub cmdkonversi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdkonversi.Click
    txtterbilang.Text = terbilang(Val(txtangka.Text))
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're converting from VB6 to VB.Net, I suggest to set `Option Strict On` right away: now you can see what kind of problems your code has and you'll probably get some hints you can use to fix it. E.g., `cbil = Trim(Str(bil))` is totally useless and completely wrong. -- Possibly, `Return` a value instead assigning a value to the Function.

Comment: BTW the [Mod operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/mod-operator) is your friend here.

Comment: @Jimi It's wrong in .NET but I think it would have behaved correctly in VB6 (though it would be more appropriate to declare `cbil` as `String` instead of having it be a `Variant`).

Comment: @Craig It probably has a meaning in VB6, it would be used to remove the space *occupied* by the sign. But this is meant to be VB.Net... (and *Type switching* like that is bad anywhere).

Comment: @Jimi I agree that the `Trim` is superfluous, but for something like this, it's not necessarily wrong to work in strings instead of in integers.  The line really does do nothing in .NET, though, because `cbil` is a integer not a variant or object.

Comment: I'm not saying that is *wrong* to work with strings here, it's treating Types as *variants* that is bad. Also because this: `Dim cbil, bil1, bil2 As Integer` has quite a different result in VB6 and VB.Net (the backward compatibility is *abused* using `Option Strict Off`) -- In the context of this question, `dim remainder = bil Mod 100` gives you ~the same result as parsing `bil.ToString()` to *extract the parts*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions in vb.net use the `Return` statement. Although the old vb6 way of assigning a value to the name of the function still works for backward compatibility, it is best to change to the .net way.
This line makes no sense.

```
cbil = Trim(Str(bil))
```

You use the old `Str()` function to convert the `Integer` to a `String`. Then you `Trim()` the `String` with another vb6 leftover. But what could you possibly be trimming? There can't be any spaces surrounding the string. Finally you try to assign the `String` to an `Integer` variable.

```
If Len(cbil) = 1 Then
```

The above makes no sense either. `cbil` is a and Integer. This translates to the .net `Int32`, a 32 bit integer. That is 4 bytes so `Len(cbil)` will always return 4, never 1.

Please get rid of `Val()` which can give unexpected results. vb.net has a slew of `CInt()`, `CLng()` etc. and `.Parse` and `.TryParse` methods to handle any conversions you will need.

```
Public Function Conversion(angka As Integer) As String
    Dim konversi As String
    Select Case angka
        Case 0 : konversi = "nol"
        Case 1 : konversi = " Satu"
        Case 2 : konversi = " Dua"
        Case 3 : konversi = " Tiga"
        Case 4 : konversi = " Empat"
        Case 5 : konversi = " Lima"
        Case 6 : konversi = " Enam"
        Case 7 : konversi = " Tujuh"
        Case 8 : konversi = " Delapan"
        Case 9 : konversi = " Sembilan"
        Case 10 : konversi = "Sepuluh"
        Case 11 : konversi = "Sebelas"
        Case 12 : konversi = "Dua belas"
        Case 13 : konversi = "Tiga belas"
        Case 14 : konversi = "Empat belas"
        Case 15 : konversi = "Lima belas"
        Case 16 : konversi = "Enam belas"
        Case 17 : konversi = "Tujuh belas"
        Case 18 : konversi = "Delapan belas"
        Case 19 : konversi = "Sembilan belas"
        Case 100 : konversi = "Seratus"
        Case Else
            konversi = ""
    End Select
    Return konversi
End Function

Public Function GetNumberWords(bil As Integer) As String
    If bil >= 0 AndAlso bil <= 19 OrElse bil = 100 Then
        Return Conversion(bil)
    ElseIf bil.ToString.Length = 2 Then
        Dim RightDigit = CInt(bil.ToString.Substring(1))
        Dim LeftDigit = CInt(bil.ToString.Substring(0, 1))
        Dim strRightDigit = Conversion(RightDigit)
        Dim strLeftDight = Conversion(LeftDigit)
        Return $"{strLeftDight} {strRightDigit}"
    Else
        Return ""
    End If
End Function

Private Sub cmdkonversi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim UserInput As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, UserInput) Then
        TextBox2.Text = GetNumberWords(UserInput)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.")
    End If
End Sub
```

I am sure this is not exactly what you want to display but it should get you started using .net methods.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but I'll try again with the code above

Comment: @Mary note that in VB6, the type of `cbil` is `Variant` not `Integer`.  The VB6 behavior is a potential trap for the unwary, and similarly so is the change in behavior in .NET in conversion of older code that relied on the other way of doing things..